# Android Studio: How to add a "start" button to CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android, button, android-studio, countdowntimer

Sup guys, i was searching about this problem everywhere, and sadly, i cant find a solution :/
My problem is in CountDownTimer, i want to start it by pressing button, but now its starts automaticaly. Here's my code:

```
`public class newgame extends Activity {
    int guessCount = 0;
    TextView textCount;
    Button buttonCount;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_newgame);

    final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    buttonCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    buttonCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            guessCount++;
            textView.setText("Clicks: " + guessCount);
        }
    });
    final TextView textic = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    CountDownTimer Count = new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            textic.setText("Time Left: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            textic.setText("Time's Up!");
            buttonCount.setEnabled(false);
        }



         };
    Count.start();
}`
```

Can someone please help me? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must place Count.start() in some onClick method. These are basics and you can easily find information about handling click events by button. Don't be lazy.

Comment: Don't forget to keep information if counter has started. Use some boolean variable and in onClick you can simply do:
if (!started){
    Count.start();
    started = true;
}
Then you should provide additional logic for stopping counter (onStop can be a good place: Count.stop(); started = false) etc. etc.

Welcome to multithread environment

Answer (score 0):

CountDownTimer has a `start()` method which you can use on button click events like

```
CountDownTimer timer = new CountDownTimer(5000, 100) {

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //your code     
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        // your code
    }
};
timer.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code

```
          private TextView txtCount, textViewTimer;

  private Button btnCount, btnRestart;

   int count = 0;

   boolean[] timerProcessing = { false };

  boolean[] timerStarts = { false };

   private MyCount timer;


      @Override




     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
btnCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnRestart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

textViewTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

timer = new MyCount(10000, 1);

btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // start timer once when button first click
        if (!timerStarts[0]) {
            timer.start();
            timerStarts[0] = true;
            timerProcessing[0] = true;
        }

        if (timerProcessing[0]) {
            count++;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
    }
});
btnRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        timerProcessing[0] = true;
        count = 0;
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        timer.cancel();
        timer.start();
    }
});


   }




         public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {

public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {

    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
    textViewTimer.setText("0:000");
    timerProcessing[0] = false;
}

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    textViewTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000 + ":"
            + millisUntilFinished % 1000);

}
```

}

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged and ultimately unhelpful. Try adding some explanation of *why* this code should help and what it is doing.

Answer (score -1):

Use this code in your Activity and i hope you will find your answer...

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
TextView tvTimer;
  long startTime = 1 * 1000;
  long interval = 1 * 100;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvTimer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTimer);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            countDownTimer.start();
        }
    });
}
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer 
{
    int  count=10;
    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) 
    {
        super(startTime, interval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        tvTimer.setText("Time's Up...!");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        int interval=(int)millisUntilFinished/100;
             tvTimer.setText("0"+interval);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged and ultimately unhelpful. Try adding some explanation of *why* this code should help and what it is doing.